# New error: Texmaker "File Not Found" after PDFLaTeX with internal embedded pdf viewer

Tags: texmaker, viewers

Texmaker is giving me a "File not found" error after running Quick Build set to PDFLaTeX + View PDF.  I have it configured to use the internal embedded pdf viewer.

Version: Texmaker 5.1.4, MikTeX 2.9

The tex file has compiled just fine in the past and the pdf output was displayed just fine too.  I am able to view the pdf in an external viewer such as Foxit, but I would prefer to use the internal viewer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you change the output directory in some way which confuses the editor?

Comment: @cfr Not to my knowledge.  How would I check that it's correct?

Comment: Is the PDF file created in the same directory as your `.tex` file? How to check depends on the editor. It might be a general setting, but it might be part of a build recipe you invoke. This shouldn't be default though. You ought to know if you did it.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it's in the same directory.

Comment: Which OS? If Windows, you probably need a Windows user. On Linux/Mac/other, I'd say start TeXMaker from the command line so you can see what it's doing. And/or see if there is anything in relevant logs. But if you're on Windows, I have no idea if any of that makes any sense at all :(.

Comment: @cfr Windows 10.  Texmaker produces a log file when compiling.

Comment: Well, you can look in the log. But if the PDF is produced and the log is from `pdftex`, it won't tell you why Texmaker can't find the file.